# Select ... where foo_id in (select id from ...) Efficiency

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, select-query

i) Between these two which one is more efficient:

```
Select A.* from A, B where A.b_id = B.id
```

or

```
Select A.* from A where A.b_id in (select id from B);
```

ii) How does `Select A.* from A where A.b_id in (select id from B);` really work? Is it internally translated into something like `Select A.* from A, B where A.b_id = B.id` or is `(select id from B)` evaluated for each row of A?

Comment: Why not run `EXPLAIN ...` for both of those statements? This will give you a very good idea of how they will be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this short article:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/

Answer (score 1):

This one is more efficient:

```
Select A.* from A, B where A.b_id = B.id
```

Yes, `Select A.* from A where A.b_id in (select id from B)` works.

And, no, `(select id from B)` is not evaluated for each row. It's evaluated only once.

Normally, JOINS are faster than using the `IN` operator.

Comment: Thanks.Does it translate to Select A.* from A where A.b_id in (1,2,3,4..) [Where 1,2,3,4... are B.id(s) that match the condition] and is equally efficient?

Comment: Opportunity to learn: you should run an `EXPLAIN` on both commands. That will give you a good idea on how they will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where those sorts of fake-joins come from, but you should join tables using `ON`, not a mass of WHERE's at the end.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON (A.b_id = B.id)
```

Comment: It's a notation that predates JOIN ON notation. Unfortunately, many Oracle books and other sources still teach it. It's clunky (especially when you start using outer joins) and most people consider it poor practice. But not everyone. Which is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various factors, including the MySQL version, the size of the tables, the existence of indexes, etc.

You should try executing `EXPLAIN ...`, or even better if supported, `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...` followed by `SHOW WARNIGS;` to try and understand what MySQL is doing.